# How does SE1.0 calculate password hash?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-dump, password

I am working on importing SE dump into askbot - could you please give a hint - how to calculate the password hash stored in file `Passwords.xml` in the SE dump?

Need to help someone migrate his SE site to Askbot.

Thank you!

Comment: I *know* this was on the old meta.SE before it was shut down. We really need to get a dump or read-only version of that site back.

Comment: E-mail team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Gonna guess its a SHA hash.  Which flavor could be determined with a little testing, assuming you have such an account that can be located in the dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent you an email directly with some information.  If anyone else has this question, send us an email at `team@stackoverflow.com`.